# Select a part of Image in Python(without using imcrop)

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, image-processing, crop

I want to select a part of the image and save it as an image file but I don't want to use imcrop() function.There are many answers for this but I don't want to use crop function.Any other methods?

Comment: What image processing library are you using? What's `imcrop` and why don't you want to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to an array and "crop" it by indexing, then convert back to an image.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Create an image for example
w, h = 512, 512 
data = np.zeros((h, w, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
data[:, :, :] = 100  # Grey image
img = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGB')
img.save('my.png')
img.show()  # View the original image

img_array = np.asarray(img)  # Convert image to an array
cropped = img_array[:100, :100, :]  # Select portion to keep

img = Image.fromarray(cropped, 'RGB')  # Convert back to image
img.save('my.png')
img.show()  # View the cropped image
```